# Swift 2.0 beta Dictionary extension

Tags: ios, macos, swift, generics, swift2

Trying to create an immutable Dictionary. The idea is to have immutable arrays of keys and values each and then pass them to a

`Dictionary constructor: let dict = Dictionary(aStringArray, aSameLengthDoubleArray)`

The following code however gives a compile time error.

```
extension Dictionary {
    init<T:Hashable,U>(keys: [T], values: [U]) {
        self.init()
        for (index, key) in keys.enumerate() {
            self[key] = values[index]
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> error:
>   cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary' with an
>   index of type 'T' self[key] = values[index]

Can someone throw some light on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know that **Dictionary** already has typealiases for its associated types key and values. The keys should be of type **Key** and value should be of type **Value**. Just like you would have **Element** type in **Array**. The above thing you could achieve simply using Key and Value as so,

```
extension Dictionary {
    init(keys: [Key], values: [Value]) {
        self.init()
        for (index, key) in keys.enumerate() {
            self[key] = values[index]
        }
    }
}
let a = Dictionary(keys: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], values: ["Michael", "Jack", "Kurt", "Jim", "Stewart"])
```

Comment: Thanks GeneratorOfOne! Your answer also helped me understand generic types vs generic functions.